# Setting frame while Loading a UIViewControllers View as a subView into a UIVIew

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

[image]

From Figure: While loading the UIViewController Bs view as a subview into the UIViewController As UIView the frame size set to the UIViewController Bs View is not reflected and as a result the tableview goes out of screen. And as a result the tableview cannot be scrolled to the end.

In ViewController B all the ui elements height and width are defined relative to the ControllerBs width and height. And while adding it to A eventhough am setting the frame for B, while debugging it is seen that the new set Frame size is not taken and it behaves as if we didnt set the frame, ie default device size is taken

Comment: From your screenshot, you should can just add a UINavigationController and set the B as the Root of the UINavigationController. No frame setting is needed.

Comment: I agreed with lowleetak，Why didn't you try to push B from A ?

Comment: ViewController A has a segment control and B is one among many viewcontroller views i wish to load inside A when the selected segment change.

Comment: @saketmurari@gmail.com